# Ruby/Rails: Why is render json: {hello: 'world'} hitting my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I have an action:

```
  def test
    _process_action_callbacks.map { |c| pp c.filter }
    render json: {hello: 'world'}
  end
```

That for some reason is calling my **current_user** function defined in my application controller.

At first I thought it was a before action that was calling my **current_user** function (hence _process_action_callbacks). But after stripping away all of my before actions the call remained. The only two before actions are part of rails:

```
:clean_temp_files
:set_turbolinks_location_header_from_session
```

I used **caller** to see where my method was getting called from. Here's the stacktrace (and method declaration):

```
def current_user
    pp caller
    # get the current user from the db.
end
```

[image]

As you can see, the current_user function is being called by the serialization_scope method in the serialization class. How do I prevent it from calling my **current_user** function?

Comment: Hey friend who downvoted my answer? Could you provide some feedback as to why you downvoted it? I'd love some help. Even though I have a solution, I still don't know why my scope isn't nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tag indicates you are using `active-model-serializers`. By default `current_user` is the scope. To customize the scope, defined in the application-controller, you can do something like

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  serialization_scope :current_admin
end
```

The above example will change the scope from `current_user` (the default) to `current_admin`.

In your case, you probably just want to set the scope in your controller (I assume it is called `SomeController` ;) ) you can write

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  serialization_scope nil 

  def test 
    render json: {hello: 'world'} 
  end 

end
```

See for complete documentation: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable#customizing-scope

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I think that the current_user function pre-dates our use of active-model-serializers and that interaction between the two was unintentional. Thanks for your help and pointing me in the right direction.